# postfix not respecting aliases

Tags: postfix, gmail, aliases

I have a small server that is suposed configured to use my gmail account to send emails about the readings the borad takes I can send emails all right but I have noticed something strange - I specified in my /etc/aliases that all users should be routed to the same email address

/etc/aliases:

```
postmaster: mail@gmail.com
readings: mail@gmail.com
root: mail@gmail.com
```

I get all the root mail all right, but nothing else. Seems like the system tries to run the mail, but with wrong address (no use of alias)

```
postfix/qmgr[1425]: 8732EC047D: from=<readings@gmail.com>, size=4740, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

I've stumbled upon information that postfix does not use aliase with account name - is it true? More importantly, how can I set the alises for other users so that all the mail is sent with the same gmail account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you have modified `/etc/aliases` you have to launch `newaliases` command.

Comment: just tried that - I logged in as readings and sent the mail all right with mail command. Seems like this solved my problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The alias file is used for routing of **incoming** emails. It does not affect the envelope sender of **outgoing** emails. That's something you need to set in whatever it is you're using to send the emails.

Comment: As written in my post, I'm using postfix - I want to instruct it to always send the mail as mail@gmail.com where mail is my email address. Obviously when it tries to send from readings account readings@gmail.com is not going to work so I want it to know to send mail using my own email. Seems like Kondybas solution worked.

Comment: Postfix is used to transport the emails. It does not *generate* them.

Comment: in that case it's the mail command plus I followed [this tutorial](https://community.runabove.com/kb/en/instances/how-to-relay-postfix-mails-via-smtp.gmail.com-on-ubuntu-14.04.html) on how to make system mail to be sent to a custom gmail account and I simply saw that only root emails were reaching me and the log pointed out it was trying to make systemuser@gmail.com instead of mail@gmail.com

Comment: The log extract you included in your question only showed the sending address. Are you trying to say that it was the recipient address you were wanting to change?

Comment: the log is what the problem is. The sending address is wrong- it tries to send as a user I can not send as because I don't have the gmail username like that. I want every user to send as the same user - so root, readings, postmaster to send AS mymail@gmail.com being the sender - hence I specified the aliases for every user to be the same.

Comment: @JennyD _"Postfix is used to transport the emails. It does not generate them."_ ehhh... MDN/DSN?

Comment: @Kondybas I wrote "***the** emails*", not just "emails".The emails in the question aren't MDN:s/DSN:s.